# Getting an "Android resource compilation failed" error while trying to build my react native app using expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to build an android apk of my react native app. I was trying two commands ***expo-cli build:android -t apk*** and ***expo build:android***. But I am getting this error repeatedly. If anyone can give any clue about this error please do the help :')

> [stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> [stderr] * What went wrong:
> [stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> [stderr] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade 
> [stderr]    > Android resource compilation failed 
> [stderr]      **/app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk41/android-shell-app/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml:13:3-57: AAPT: error: invalid color**. 
> [stderr]
> [stderr]      **/app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk41/android-shell-app/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeReleaseResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.**
> [stderr]
> [stderr] * Try:
> [stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> [stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> [stderr] BUILD FAILED in 31s

**I have attached a screenshot of the error I am getting. Please give a look.**

*[Build failed with an exception.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZwrz.png)*

Comment: Have you recently added Firebase to your project? Looks like you might be missing your google-services.json file which you can download from the Firebase console.

Comment: What is the value of line `13` in `app/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml`?